# Java - Stream Filter to get Last Day of several months in a list of dates (not calendar last day)

Tags: java, java-stream, yearmonth

**Query:**
To filter the data below to find the last date of each month in the list. Note that in this context,
the last date of month in the data may or
may not match with the last date of the calendar month.
The expected output is shown in second list.

**Research:**

- I believe `TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()` will not help in this case as the last date in the list may or may not match with calendar month's last date.
- I checked several questions on Stack Overflow and I Googled as well,
  but I was unable to find something similar to my need.

I hope the issue is clear and points me in the direction on how this can be done with streams,
as I don't want to use a `for` loop.

**Sample Data:**

| Date | Model | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27-11-1995 | ABC | 241 | 621 |
| 27-11-1995 | XYZ | 3456 | 7878 |
| 28-11-1995 | ABC | 242 | 624 |
| 28-11-1995 | XYZ | 3457 | 7879 |
| 29-11-1995 | ABC | 243 | 627 |
| 29-11-1995 | XYZ | 3458 | 7880 |
| 30-11-1995 | ABC | 244 | 630 |
| 30-11-1995 | XYZ | 3459 | 7881 |
| 01-12-1995 | ABC | 245 | 633 |
| 01-12-1995 | XYZ | 3460 | 7882 |
| 04-12-1995 | ABC | 246 | 636 |
| 04-12-1995 | XYZ | 3461 | 7883 |
| 27-12-1995 | ABC | 247 | 639 |
| 27-12-1995 | XYZ | 3462 | 7884 |
| 28-12-1995 | ABC | 248 | 642 |
| 28-12-1995 | XYZ | 3463 | 7885 |
| 29-12-1995 | ABC | 249 | 645 |
| 29-12-1995 | XYZ | 3464 | 7886 |
| 01-01-1996 | ABC | 250 | 648 |
| 01-01-1996 | XYZ | 3465 | 7887 |
| 02-01-1996 | ABC | 251 | 651 |
| 02-01-1996 | XYZ | 3466 | 7888 |
| 29-01-1996 | ABC | 252 | 654 |
| 29-01-1996 | XYZ | 3467 | 7889 |
| 30-01-1996 | ABC | 253 | 657 |
| 30-01-1996 | XYZ | 3468 | 7890 |
| 31-01-1996 | ABC | 254 | 660 |
| 31-01-1996 | XYZ | 3469 | 7891 |

<sup>[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvVa9.png)</sup>

**Output required:**

| Date | Model | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30-11-1995 | ABC | 244 | 630 |
| 30-11-1995 | XYZ | 3459 | 7881 |
| 29-12-1995 | ABC | 249 | 645 |
| 29-12-1995 | XYZ | 3464 | 7886 |
| 31-01-1996 | ABC | 254 | 660 |
| 31-01-1996 | XYZ | 3469 | 7891 |

<sup>[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aeo60.png)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a combination of `groupingBy` and `maxBy` will probably do.

I assume each record of the table to be of type `Event`:

```java
record Event(LocalDate date, String model, int start, int end) { }
```

To get the last days of the month which are within the table, we could utilize `groupingBy`. In order to group this, we could first create a grouping type. Below, I created an `EventGrouping` record<sup>1</sup>, with a `static` method to convert an `Event` to an `EventGrouping`. Your desired output suggests that you want to group by each year-month-model combination, so we just picked those two properties:

```java
public record EventGrouping(YearMonth yearMonth, String model) {
        
    public static EventGrouping fromEvent(Event event) {
        return new EventGrouping(YearMonth.from(event.date()), event.model());
    }
}
```

Then, we could get our desired result like this:

```java
events.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        EventGrouping::fromEvent,
        Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Event::date))
    ));
```

What happens here is that all stream elements are grouped by our `EventGrouping`, and then the "maximum value" of each of the event groups is picked. The maximum value is, of course, the most recent date of that certain month.

Note that `maxBy` returns an `Optional`, for the case when a group is empty. Also note that the resulting `Map` is unordered.

We could fix both of these issues by using `collectingAndThen` and a *map factory* respectively:

```java
Map<EventGrouping, Event> map = events.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(
        EventGrouping::fromEvent,
        () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparing(EventGrouping::yearMonth)
            .thenComparing(EventGrouping::model)),
        collectingAndThen(maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Event::date)), Optional::get)
    ));
```

<sup>Note: `groupingBy`, `collectingAndThen` and `maxBy` are all static imports from `java.util.stream.Collectors`.</sup>

- We added a `Supplier` of a `TreeMap`. A `TreeMap` is a `Map` implementation with a predictable order by a given comparator. This allows us to iterate over the resulting entries ordered by year–month–model.
- `collectingAndThen` allows us to apply a function to the result of the given `Collector`. As already mentioned, `maxBy` returns an `Optional`, because `maxBy` is not applicable if there are no elements in the source stream. However, in our case, this can never happen. So we can safely map the `Optional` to its contained value.

---

<sup>1</sup> Instead of writing a custom type, you could also use an existing class holding two arbitrary values, such as a `Map.Entry`, a `Pair` or even a `List<Object>`.

Comment: It is giving an error : Bad return type in lambda expression: TreeMap<EventGrouping, Object> cannot be converted to TreeMap<EventGrouping, Event> am I missing something here ?

Comment: @iCoder That's probably the compiler not being able to infer the correct types. Under JDK 17 it'll work. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: It'll probably also work if you help the compiler a little by using `() -> new TreeMap<EventGrouping, Event>…` there.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ Ultimate & JDK - 16.0.2 If I help the compiler to infer as suggested it is giving error - https://i.imgur.com/fAbjdNr.png

Comment: Well, what type is `data`?

Comment: First field is LocalDate, second is String, followed by a few fields which are of type double. I am reading this data from MySQL db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240672/discussion-between-mc-emperor-and-icoder).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a `Map<YearMonth, List<LocalDate>` and parse all your dates and fill your map. After that you sort all your lists and your last (or firstdepending on sorting order) value in each list will be your desired value